# How to uniquely select rows that match two values with postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I'm building an SMS application and I have a use case for returning all rows in the SMS table and return the last 5 activities. Obviously, all activities are to or from unique phone numbers but duplicates should not be included as it can happen that two subsequent SMSes are sent. And that should only show as 1 activity instead of 2. Let's say there are 6 messages exchanged between number X and userPhoneNmber. Then, it should count that 6 as one, with a date field that is the most recent one amongst those 6 messages.

So, I'm trying to come up with a query for Postgres that will do something like this: select unique rows that match one or two values on a column and then sort it based on another field. But are stuck at returning the most recent timestamp between X number of messages.

```
      .createQueryBuilder('smse')
      .where({
        from: userPhonenumber, AND
        to: userPhonenumber
      })
      .distinct() should return the most recent createdAt field among matching rows
      .orderBy('createdAt') 
      .limit(5 for paging)
      .getRawMany()
```

Comment: What columns does table *smse* have?

Comment: these are the 2 relevant fields: userphonenumber, createdat

Comment: My understanding is that rows counts as duplicates if they involve SMSes sent between the same two parties. But with a single "userphonenumber", this cannot be detected. I propose you rewrite your question such that it includes sample input data and the desired outcome.

Comment: Actually there is from and to fields